# What does it mean when a * follows the type name in C++?

Tags: c++

I am a Java guy trying to learn C++.

I came across some code where following the type name, there is a *. For example:

```
char* socialNum[125][9];
```

and

```
CSampleDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
```

What does the star mean?

Comment: if you see `*` in C/C++, it's generally either multiplication, or a pointer. in this case, pointer.

Comment: I respectfully suggest that if you're trying to learn basic C++ syntax, do so with a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), rather than via Stack Overflow.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was using a book but I was constantly skipping since so much is the same as in Java. It was hard to find the points that I didn't already know

Comment: @Imray: I suggest skipping back to the start.  Other than superficialities, there are very few similarities between Java and C++.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but before you start asking "what does the `&` mean" and "what does the `&&` mean" and "what does the `virtual` mean", could you just grab a C++ text book and read it for a week?

Comment: Get a better book, or be a bit more diligent in reading the one you have.  It is *critical* that you understand pointers, and you won't get a very complete understanding from SO posts.

Comment: You should accept either @Martijn Courteaux 's answer or mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that the variable is a pointer.

```
int myInt = 4;
int *myPointer = &myInt;
```

Now, `myPointer` points to the integer `myInt`. Pointing to something is basically holding the memory address of that something.

---

Since you said you come from Java, this in Java:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(); // obj is a reference (or pointer)
```

would be equivalent with this in C++:

```
MyClass *obj = new MyClass(); // obj is here a pointer as well.

// and once you are done with obj, don't forget to free the memory:
delete obj;
```

Comment: He has a Java background. You should show him how to `delete` stuff first.

Answer (score 0):

`*` means it is a `pointer` to a piece of data.

Take, for example, these:

```
int *myInt;
char *myChar;
MyClass *objectOfClass;
```

All of these are *pointers* to the data in memory. The value of the pointer is an `int`, which is the address (location) in memory of that data.

Comment: Does it matter if the `*` precedes the variable name or follows it?

Comment: Pointers(*) and references(&) must precede the variable name.

Comment: You can declare it as `int* myInt` or `int *myInt`, but you *cannot* declare it as `int myInt*`. See @criticalSeleciton's comment.